# Laravel Insert Multiple Table And Multiple Data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I Have problem with inserting data to 3 table with 1 form.
i want to get dynamically section_id after section table saved. the section_id will put on content table.

here is my code

```
// insert course
$Course = new Course;
$Course->title = $request->title;
$Course->goal = $request->goal;
$Course->description = $request->description;
$Course->image = $request->image;
$Course->id_category = $request->id_category;
$Course->id_level_course = $request->id_level_course;
$Course->id_author = $request->id_author;
$Course->save();
$Course_id = $Course->id;
// insert course

// insert section
foreach($request->get('section_title') as $index => $value){
  if($value != null){ // check not null request value
    $Section = new Section;
    $Section->title = $value;
    $Section->id_course = $Course_id;
    $Section->save();
    $Section_id = $Section->id;        

  }
}
// insert section

// insert content
   foreach($request->get('content_title') as $index => $value){
      if($value != null){ // check not null request value
        $Content = new Content;
        $Content->title = $value;
        $Content->id_section = $Section_id;
        $Content->save();
      }
    }
// insert content
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Is there multiple section_titles?

Comment: @Adi Gunawan Hidayat what should happend if you have several not null Sections and several not null Content?

Comment: Are you using  auto-incrementing IDs?

Comment: when i save the section_id on content_table is the same data. but i want the section_id is dynamicaly with when insert multiple to content_table

Comment: @okante i want  $Section_id; value is dynamicaly not last insert section table

Comment: i think it gives u multiple ids?

Comment: add each content in section loop, see below for one Content per section

Comment: Sidenote: Take a look at [`save`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) which (if you correctly defined the relationships) can be used like `$Course->sections()->save([/**/])` . Not a solution, but a more "laravel way" of doing this

Comment: how do you know that content_title_n should be for section_1 or section_n. give us your resquest vars...

Answer (score 0):

If `content_title` and `section_title` is comma separated string then you need to `explode` it before passing to `foreach` loop:

```
$titles = explode(',',$request->get('content_title') );
foreach($titles as $index => $value){
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert each contents after section.

```
$contents = $request->get('content_title')
foreach($request->get('section_title') as $index => $value){
  if($value != null){ // check not null request value
    $Section = new Section;
    $Section->title = $value;
    $Section->id_course = $Course_id;
    $Section->save();
    $Section_id = $Section->id;        
// insert content
   $title = isset($contents[$index]) ? $contents[$index]: null;
   if($title != null){ // check not null request value
        $Content = new Content;
        $Content->title = $title;
        $Content->id_section = $Section_id;
        $Content->save();
    }
  }
}
```

// insert section

Comment: But i want on the content_table can multiple insert too. on your code just insert 1 record on content_table

Comment: update your question with a 'var_dump' of your request variable content_title and section_title

Comment: section_title is like 'Lear Laravel';
content_title is like 'Installation Laravel, Instalation composer'